# BeeLink NUC UEFI Shell Command to Format Partition

Tags: windows-10, installation, uefi, format, boot-partition

I have a Beelink NUC that powers on to a "UEFI Interactive Shell v2.2" and Shell>.

I have a installation media USB for Win10, but when I view the current partitions it says unable to installed on hard disk space because partition must be formatted as NTFS. Only the first partitions allows for to *Format* the drive, but after I do so nothing changes.

Sorry if this has been addressed, but I've looked around and haven't found any relevant questions - please forward any if you know of one.

I'm familiar with these types of installs, but not from this boot screen.

Thanks.

Edit Note: USB is installation Media, not bootable USB.

Comment: There appears to be something missing. Why are there partitions on the drive? // It’s possible the drive is MBR-partitioned. GPT is required. Try _deleting_ all partitions.

Comment: You need *installation* media, not a bootable drive.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik correction it is installation media, not bootable drive. Wow, so I deleted the partitions and was able to proceed. Thanks so much, I was scared to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that there’s something missing here. Why are there already partitions on the drive you want to install to?

---

If you are fine with formatting these partitions, you probably don’t care about any data inside. So instead, you should delete them.

You (apparently) want to install Windows in UEFI mode. This means Windows Setup will only install to a drive that is GPT-partitioned. It’s possible your drive is MBR-partitioned. It’s likely you misread the error message and it wasn’t about NTFS at all.

Windows Setup will only convert drives with no user partitions (only free space listed in Setup) to GPT.